# How to debug cron job - codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

My cron job is triggering properly from a godaddy shared server:

```
wget `http://www.domain/APP/index.php?/cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST`
```

There are no errors returned in the cron result:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.php?%2Fcron_jobs%2Fcron_job_TEST'
```

I set the test to write to a text file - and also to write to a database table.

When I test this - by visiting the URL - `http://www.domain/APP/index.php?/cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST`
The text file and table are written to properly.

But when the cron runs - there is no result to the text file or the database table.

**CONTROLLER/FUNTION 'cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST':**

```
// CRON_1
    public function cron_job_TEST(){

        file_put_contents("test_cron_job.txt", "cron_job_TEST-> ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . "\n", FILE_APPEND);


        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `TEST_CRON` (`ID`, `DATE`) VALUES ('', NOW());");


    }// END CRON_1
```

I have also tried the `/web/cgi-bin/php5 $HOME/html/` methods without luck.
I thought the point of the wget was that it would behave just as though you are visiting the URL.

What could be going wrong here?

How do I debug this?

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog`.  Errors with cron usually go there.

Comment: not seeing that directory in this particular godaddy account

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be much help then as I'm unfamiliar with the GoDaddy hosting setup.

Comment: Does the server response 200 OK - not indicate there is no error? So therefore there would not be any error logged?

Comment: Not necessarily.  There might not be an error with your script, but there could be an error with the cron configuration or how you've defined the command executed by cron.  Those will show up in the system log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using wget to fetch your file from a web server, you should execute the command directly from the command line by invoking PHP on your codeigniter's index.php file:

```
php /path/to/your/project/html/index.php cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST
```

If you execute your codeigniter app this way, you should be able to see the output and also the errors that might bubble up during its execution.

I'd also suggest writing a log file from your cron method so you can output values and, if you are clever, be sure which branches of your code are executing.

EDIT: you might also alter your cron job, whichever method you choose, to route the output of the cron job into a file so you might have some clue about what went down:

```
wget `http://www.domain/APP/index.php?/cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST` > /path/to/file.txt
```

EDIT: I think you can also route both stderr and stdout to the same file like so

```
wget `http://www.domain/APP/index.php?/cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST` &> /path/to/file.txt
```

Obviously, the user that owns this cron job must have permission to write that output file if the file already exists or must have permission to write the directory if the file does not exist.

Once the cron job has run, you might be able to look in this file and get a better idea of what transpired.

Comment: I have tried this method - no luck... I'll try again... thanks.

Comment: @Creeperstanson your post doesn't have the php command at the beginning. Alternatively, consider routing the output from your wget statement into a file

Comment: are you sure it is /index.php cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST and not /index.php? cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST ?

Comment: Look at my post.  See that first bit of code? It starts with **php**. A PHP file won't execute on its own unless a) it has its executable permission set and b) it starts with a shebang (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) ). You have to specify from the command line what program is to be used to interpret your php file. You may need to specify /usr/bin/php instead of just php.

Comment: and NO you don't put a question mark after index.php when executing directly from the command line -- this would just cause BASH to complain that it can't find the file named **index.php?**

Comment: When I try the "/web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/html/APP/index.php cron_jobs/cron_job_TEST"" method - I get this error:
"Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html
No input file specified."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132863/discussion-between-s-imp-and-creeperstanson).